# swift addTarget Multiple parameter

Tags: xcode, swift, function, parameters, arguments

I'm new in Swift 2.2

I want to addTarget Button with multiple parameters

```
let users_id = 123
let contests_id = 456
cell.acceptButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.acceptAction(_:users_id:contests_id)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func acceptAction(sender: AnyObject,contests_id:Int, users_id: Int){
    print(contests_id)
    print(users_id)
}
```

But It not works.

It is possible to addTarget with multiple parameters?

If not, How can I design that function?

Comment: No, you can't send an action with multiple parameters. How do you get `users_id` and `contests_id`? Are they textfields / dropdown somewhere?

Comment: @CodeDifferent From cell in UITableView.

Comment: You can make a custom `Button` subclass, give it `users_id` and `contests_id` instance variables, and then use those in `acceptAction`.

Comment: @Robert Thanks It works Very Nice Idea !